# I'm trying to getting image from Highchart

Tags: javascript, php, html, highcharts

I'm trying to getting image from Highchart.

Highchart provides download chart image function. A context button with a menu appears in the top right corner of the chart.
(http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume)

I'd like to create chart image to designated folder in my server when I click button.

How do I develop this using php?

Comment: Welcome! If you can, add some more tags so you get more people involved. For example: "javascript"?

Comment: Setup [exporting server](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server) from Highcharts. I think it's good starting point for what you want to achieve. I suggest to go with server based on Java an PhantomJS, because PHP+Batik is an old solution with some bugs/limitations.